# Cannot open backup '' Operating system error 5(Access is denied.)

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to restore a `.bak` file from one server to another server. Please see me syntax:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [NewDB]
FROM DISK = '\\aps-sql111\D$\MSSQL\Backup\OLDDB.bak'
WITH 
MOVE 'OLDDB' TO 'M:\MSSQL\NewDB.mdf',
MOVE 'OLDDB_log' TO 'M:\MSSQL\NewDB.ldf',
REPLACE,
STATS=10
```

All I keep seeing is:

> Cannot open backup device ''. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.).

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you are trying to restore over the network, accessing a bak file that is not local to the destination server: with the default sql configuration you cannot do that.

the default setup is to run the sql service as a local user (network service or local service, usually): a local user cannot access resources on remote machines.

there are at least 3 solutions:

- copy the file locally in a folder accessible to the user used by the sql service
- change the configuration of the sql service to run as a user that can access the backup folder over the network (i would not do that on a production system)
- copy the bak file on a removeble storage to move the data from source to destination (or copy the bak on a SAN/NAS that can be mapped onto the destination server)

Comment: The issue here is that the .bak file here is about 600gb large. I am having space issues. Is there no other way to run that script?

Comment: make the sql service run as a user that can access that folder over the network. that is not a trivial change or something i would do on a production environment. see my edit

Comment: @user3424320: regarding the space issue, is the backup file compressed with native SQL compression?

Answer (score 1):

If we want to **restore database using network share** as described, we must perform few steps before the restore operation itself. **The network share must be mapped as a network drive in the session in which SQL Server is running.**

**1. Map a Network drive in File Explorer**

- Open **File Explorer**
- Select **This PC** from the left pane. Then, on the **Computer tab**, select **Map network drive**
- In the **Drive** list, select a drive letter.
- In the **Folder** box, type the path of the folder or computer, or select **Browse** to find the folder or computer. To connect every time you sign in to your PC, select **Reconnect at sign-in.**
- Select **Finish**.

  [image: Mapping a network drive]

**2. Map a Network drive in SQLServer**

Please execute following commands in SQL Server Management Studio:

- `exec sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1 go reconfigure go`
- `exec sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell',1 go reconfigure with override go`
- `xp_cmdshell 'net use z: \\server_name\drive_name passwordhere /user:DOMAIN\USERNAME'`

Now you should be able to see network drive from restore wizard.

Keep in mind, however, that **this ability will be removed once we restart SQL server.** So **to prevent this we can create a stored procedure like below and make it a startup procedure for the SQL service.** This way, all of the above is done for you every time SQL starts (such as machine reboots, etc.)

**Map Network Share Permanently in SSMS**

1. Create stored procedure

- `CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[mapdrives] AS exec xp_cmdshell 'net use z: \\server_name\drive_name passwordhere /user:DOMAIN\USERNAME' GO`

2. Enable that stored procedure to run at startup:

- `exec sp_procoption 'mapdrives','startup','true'`

Now we can reach network drive also using PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

One way is change log on type from Built-in-account to user account on SQL Server configuration and use an user with enough permission on network.

- Open SQL Server configuration management
- go to SQL Server Services
- Chose SQL Server ([your instance name])
- Right click on service and click **properties**
- select tab **Log On**
- Change to This account
- Browse a user with access on network directory permission
- Set user and password
- Restart service

If you need working on JOB Backup set this user on SQL Server Agent Service.